# Exclude [exclude]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

There are currently <s>845</s> <s>672</s> <s>350</s> <s>149</s> <s>10</s> 0 questions tagged [exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exclude) (6 followers). There is no tag wiki, only a excerpt that states:

> Exclude is a generic term for the process of identifying a subset of code or data which should not be used in a particular context.

The most voted questions tagged with it range from [Linux grep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1491514/1743880) to [`.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848500/1743880) or [Apache Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028534/1743880).

All the questions tagged with it are about *excluding* something. However, all of those questions have the word "exclude" in the title so adding this tag does not add any information. Besides, I do not see how someone could be an expert in [exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exclude).

Note that this tag has a lot of cousins:

- [excluding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excluding): <strike>24</strike> 0 questions, no wiki
- [exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exclusion): <strike>80</strike> 0 questions, no wiki
- [exclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exclusive): <strike>61</strike> 0 questions, no wiki
- [excludes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excludes): <strike>15</strike> 0 questions, no wiki
- [exclusive-arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exclusive-arc): <strike>2</strike> 0 questions, no wiki
- [exclude-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exclude-pattern): <strike>1</strike> 0 questions, no wiki

I think this tag and all of its family should be burned.

[open unanswered questions, downvote for roomba-cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bexclude%5d%20answers%3a0%20closed%3a0%20score%3a0..)

Comment: I think it can be useful for [tag:maven] questions where there can be an `<excludes>` element in the pom, but we really don't need 5 of those tags. [tag:exclusive-arc] would be fine if it were defined.

Comment: That would be quite an exclusive club of experts.

Comment: Why do we have a tag for [exclusive]?????? I don't see the sense on it...

Comment: Every time I see the word pom I have to double-take.

Comment: Man this tag is dying soon. I guess many guys are out there burninating :P

Comment: FYI the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room has been working on this tag. Tunaki feel free to join us in there and help out

Comment: @durron597 I've been burninating this tag on some of the questions myself, didn't know there even was a SO Close Vote Reviewers room.

Comment: Please don't burn the tag on questions that have close votes, it helps us keep the effort organized, so we can find them by filtering in the close vote queue

Comment: @durron597 Duly noted!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the community at large, the tag [exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exclude) and all of its family is now

## ***BURNINATED***

[image]