# Let's permanently [exclude] this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blocklist-request

[exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exclude) has [previously been burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303434/6296561) and is now back with another 75 questions. According to [rodgort](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/zombies?tag=exclude), it has been revived thrice since its initial burnination. It's time to get rid of it for good.

While not listed in the burnination, all the burn criteria are met; the concept of exclusion goes beyond programming, and means different things in different contexts both in and out of programming. It doesn't describe the content, and it does not add any meaningful information.

Off the top of my head, the meanings include exclusion of people from a group (both related and unrelated to code), exclusion as negating regex, exclusion in a search (such as search word exclusion, or other metadata, depending on the search engine), excluding things from a list (once again code and non-code related), and [exclusion zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusion_zone).

Comment: Pss, [include] exist too.

Comment: So much to burninate, so little time :')

Comment: Speaking of blocklist message for the tag, we should probably use something along these lines (at least it should indicate that the blocked tag isn't sufficiently scoped to be added to questions at all): "Tags should unambiguously describe a topic in the programming context. Generic tags often lack the scope to adequately describe the topic - choose or create a more specific tag."

Comment: can 75 people really be that wrong, even 2015 it should have been kept alive, maybe it would have already thousands of very good questions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, where people can be wrong *at scale*!  Realistically the issue is that askers (reasonably) do not know or care how the tagging system is supposed to work, they just try to find some related keywords.  They're not thinking about whether the already-existing tag they're adding is a useful attribute to sort questions by.

Comment: @nbk alternately: thousands of very good questions _about **what**_?  This tag does not meaningfully describe a question's topic, nor is it sufficiently specific to aid searching or connecting askers to answerers.

Comment: @Ryan almost all tags that are around of 7 yea4s get a lot of attention and even exclude and include will have thousands of questions and answers

Comment: @nbk Yes, and that's a problem, because it's _not a useful tag_.  You have no idea what those thousands of questions would be _about_, because the tag adds no useful information.

Comment: @RyanM any´d you can't tell if the tag would contribute to that question, so it doesn't hurt tokeep it

Comment: @nbk if you wish to provide _specific_ arguments that the tag is useful and should be kept, you are encouraged to do so.  "you can't tell if the tag would contribute to that question" is not such an argument, as it could apply to literally any tag.  There is significant evidence provided here and in the previous meta question that it does *not* contribute meaningful information to questions, and so far in the nearly 7 years since the first burnination, no one has come forward to provide any evidence that it *does*.

Comment: @RyanM the concept of tags is to help other find question in their field, but but it also shows the intention what the asker wants, as more tags are available, more concepts can be transported or even inspire new ideas

Comment: The block for this tag is now in place - request to remove it from the 80 existing posts is pending.

Comment: `[exclude]` has been successfully burninated 